# Prevent WSO2 AM of dropping authorization token from request

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

As per documentation

> When you send an API request to the backend, you pass a token in the Authorization header of the request. The API Gateway uses this token to authorize access, and then drops it from the outgoing message.
>   [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Pass+a+Custom+Authorization+Token+to+the+Backend)

I want to pass this token to the backend for every published API. What is the correct place to configure such behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncomment below configuration in `repository/conf/api-manager.xml` and set `false`.

```
<RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage>true</RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage>
```

Answer (score 4):

From API Manager version 3.0.0 onwards [configuration model has been changed](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/#configuration-catalog). So any changes done in api-manager.xml get reverted after the server restart.

Now we need to change `<API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml`

[Uncomment and set the following lines](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/reference/config-catalog/#api-m-oauth-configurations):

```
[apim.oauth_config]
enable_outbound_auth_header = true
```

> `enable_outbound_auth_header`   **string**
> *Default: FALSE*   **If TRUE, sends Auth header to the backend as received
> from the client.**